# Multer: How to have the filename same with the one save in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

Right now I'm able to basically `save` **just** the `name` or `originalname` of the image `file` in both:-

1. database (using `mongoose`) and,
2. `image folder`

But this way of doing it will have **flaw** when trying to `delete` an `image`. For example if I try to `upload` the same `image` **twice**. `Multer` will not **copy** the new image (the same image) again in the `destination` `location` or `folder` (`/upload`). So if later on, I try to delete a `data` from:- (bare in mind that right now I've **two data** that have the same **image name**)

1. database (using `mongoose`)
2. delete the image affiliate with the data from folder `/upload`

The **other** `data` that use the **same image** will not have one anymore.

So, I've tried putting `new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:\.Z]/g, "")` on the `filename` on both the image saved in `local folder` `/upload` and `document` in `mongoDb`. But obviously that won't work cause the generated `date` slightly different for both case.

Below is my current code:-

- Multer.js

```js
// Mutler
const multer = require('multer')
// Path
const path = require('path')
// File Remove
const fileRemove = require('fs')

const {
  // File Base FOlder Location
  FILE_BASE_FOLDER_LOCATION = path.resolve(__dirname + '/', '../'),
  // Image Folder Location
  IMAGE_FOLDER_LOCATION = FILE_BASE_FOLDER_LOCATION + '/upload/',
} = process.env

// storage img
const storageImgFile = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, IMAGE_FOLDER_LOCATION)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    // renaming the image file to have the 'date' and the original file name 
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:\.Z]/g, "") + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
})

// filter img types
const filterImgFile = (req, file, cb) => {
  const fileTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
  
  if(fileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) cb(null, true)
  else cb('Only .png .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!', false)
}

// Img FIle Upload Middleware
const uploadImgFile = multer({
  storage: storageImgFile,
  filterImgFile: filterImgFile
  // limits: { fieldSize: 10000000000 }
})

// Img Removing Handler
const handleImgRemove = (res, imgName) => {
  fileRemove.unlink(IMAGE_FOLDER_LOCATION + imgName, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        error: `Failed at removing file from upload folder`,
        data: err
      })
    }
  })
}

module.exports = {
  imgFolderLocation: IMAGE_FOLDER_LOCATION,
  uploadImgFile,
  handleImgRemove,
}
```

- `AddNewImage Route`:-

```js
router.post('/add', uploadImgFile.single('file'), async(req, res) => {
  let { desc } = req.body

  const image = new Image({
    // the date will be slightly different or not same with the 'imagename' saved in 'local' destination
    imgName: new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:\.Z]/g, "") + '-' + req.file.originalname,
    desc: desc
  });

  image.save()
  .then(res => {

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      count: res.length,
      data: res
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: `Failed to upload new image!`,
      data: err
    })
  })
})
```

- `DeleteImage Route`:-

```js
router.delete('/delete/:id', async(req, res) => {
  await Image.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
  .then(data => {
    // - remove image from upload folder
    handleImgRemove(res, data.imgName)

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      count: data.length,
      data: data
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: `Failed to delete image from DB!`,
      data: err
    })
  })
})
```

I'm hoping to get both (`imgName` saved in `mongoDb`) and `filename` saved in `local` destination folder `/upload` will be the same. But I can't. So how can I make sure that `both` of them will have the same `naming system or ways`?

Answer (score 2):

```
const multer = require("multer");
const uuid = require("uuid").v4;
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    const originalname = `${uuid()}${ext}`;
    cb(null, originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

npm install uuid

You would need to give each image a unique name using uuid, you can do this by giving each image a filename like in the example. This will also slove the problem where the same file won't be stored twice. You can additionally add the current date to the filename to further reduce the chance of two files having the same name.

This is what the image object will look like

```
  {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'image1.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: '31d41f39-b4ad-467c-bb09-601596240fe8.jpg',
    path: 'uploads\\31d41f39-b4ad-467c-bb09-601596240fe8.jpg',
    size: 961388
  }
```